# MyBatis doesn't return all rows in <collection>, when select query is executed to bring all corresponding rows

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, mybatis

`<collection property="mole" select="selectAllMoleByUserId" column="id"></collection>` should bring all 90 rows but it brings only 10 rows. I have checked the query on database it works fine. I am using mybatis-spring version 1.1.0.

```
<resultMap id="base_map" type="com.application.User">
    <id column="id" property="id" jdbcType="INTEGER" />
    <result column="mint_id" property="mintId" jdbcType="INTEGER" />
    <result column="first_name" property="firstName" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
    <result column="last_name" property="lastName" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
  </resultMap>


<resultMap id="user_map" type="com.application.User" extends="base_map">
    <result column="first_login" property="firstLogin" jdbcType="BIT" />
    <result column="failed_login_count" property="failedLoginCount" jdbcType="INTEGER" />
    <result column="clear_id" property="clearId" jdbcType="INTEGER" />
<collection property="mole" select="selectAllMoleByUserId" column="id"></collection>
  </resultMap>

<resultMap id="mole_result_map" type="com.application.Mole">
        <id column="id" property="id" jdbcType="INTEGER" />
        <result column="description" property="description" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
        <result column="firstname" property="firstname" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
<result column="lastname" property="lastname" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
    </resultMap>

  <select id="selectAllMoleByUserId" parameterType="java.lang.Integer" resultMap="mole.mole_result_map">
    select m.id, m.firstname, m.lastname, m.description
    from mole m
    where m.user_id=#{userId} and
    m.access_granted = true
    and m.entity_deleted = false
  </select>
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the `and` keyword between the first two `where` conditions.

Comment: that is typing error i will edit it. Still the issue persist. Thanks.

Comment: can you post the query executed by mybatis along with its parameters? you can find it in the app logs

Comment: I think it has something to do with lazy loading. I cannot post the logs as per the policy of the place I work. But I can tell that logs also show only 10 rows fetched and not all 90 rows. And if I take the same query and run on database it gives 90 rows.

Comment: Sometimes, Running the query on db will give you more rows if the Cartesian product happens. However, mybatis groups such a Cartesian records as per the id column set up.

Comment: Thanks for the help, actually since I had used id in result map so all results with same id were aggregated leaving some data missing as ids will be unique. So, I then changed id to result in result map which gave me all the columns.